# Ubuntu 9.10 3 monitors setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-9.10, xorg

My desktop machine is on Ubuntu and I have 3 monitors, until now everything was working fine but since I have upgraded to Karmic Koala 9.10, my setup is kind of broken.

I have 2 video cards, 1 connect two screens exact same model and use a twinview so I can move windows around those two. The third screen is connected to the second video card and work in a separate x server.

Before upgrading when I maximized some windows in the twinview (the 2 same screen) it gently maximized to the size of one screen. Now it maximizes across the two screens which is not really useful.

Here come my [xorg.conf](http://pastebin.com/m7c8310d3), last details but important one, I am running compiz which means xinerama is a no go for me.

If someone has encountered the same problem and has solution or idea it would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, fixed the problem

seem disabling "Detects output" and inputing the output since (i.e. `1680x1200+0+0`).

I had also to play with gconftool-2 to create a new screen option in Gconf.

for the full details see my [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305666) on ubuntu forum.